# How to declare a classpath in a .properties file?

Tags: java, xml, maven

In my project there is a XML file located in the following path.

```
home/Project/framework/src/test/resources/TestPrograms.xml
```

Below shows the **myproperty.properties** file coding.

```
projecthieararchy.read.derectory=classpath/TestPrograms.xml
```

Since the path is depends from `PC to PC`, what will be the classpath for the XML file on the **.properties** file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't put `/` at the beginning, it automatically look in your project directory. This will solve your issue:

```
projecthieararchy.read.derectory=src/test/resources/TestPrograms.xml
```

Comment: You're welcome, if you don't put `/` at the beginning, it automatically look in your project directory.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong-headed.  It's circular: "I need the CLASSPATH to read the .properties file, but I have to have the .properties file to set the CLASSPATH."

You set the CLASSPATH outside of your app.

You don't need that directory setting in the .properties file.  Put it in your CLASSPATH and load the .xml file using getResourceAsStream(), like [this](http://www.factorypattern.com/how-to-readwrite-java-properties-files/).